How can I Bind TextField in SwiftUI while still using it to store favourites?
I have a textfield where a user can manually enter a location string. This is bound to my observed object AppState which i've re-labelled (app) which has a @Published var called destination. This works fine and I am able to bind the manually typed text in the text field like so:
TextField("Destination", text: $app.destination)

I have started trying to implement a favourites system where the user can save and change up to 4 destinations to quickly enter without re-typing (Only 1 is entered into the textfield at a time).
When the user presses on one of their favourites, the favourite appears in the textfield, there they can change it by typing a new one an saving it, or pressing a new favourite which replaces the one in the textField. The user must also have the option of not entering a favourite at all and be able to enter a random one too.
I have got this part working all reasonably well so far and am happy with the functionality.
My issue here is that I can't figure out how to bind whatever is in the textfield to my ObservedObject app.destination. After some trouble shooting I have found that only the manually entered text will store in app.destination. Having a favourite appear in the textfield does not bind.
I have tried variations on .onChange() and .onTapGesture() and .focused() to run an if/else block which would simply assign the text in the textfield to app.destination but it is still buggy and you can't then save a new favourite...
I'm going around in circles trying to figure this out and would greatly appreciate some help.
I have a minimum reproducible example for you to copy and paste. Thank you
Main View
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var favoritesViewModel = FavoritesViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var app = AppState()
    @State private var newLocation = ""
    @State private var selectedLocationIndex = 0
    @State private var userSelectedFavourite: String = ""
    @State private var favouritePressed: Bool = false
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                //.........THIS IS THE ISSUE TEXTFIELD
                TextField("Destination", text: (favouritePressed && !isFocused) ? $favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations[selectedLocationIndex] : $newLocation)
                //.....................................
                .focused($isFocused)
                .contentShape(.rect)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 280, height: 60)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                )
                
                Button("Save") {
                    saveLocation(locationIndex: selectedLocationIndex)
                }
            }
            
            Picker("Favorite Locations", selection: $selectedLocationIndex) {
                ForEach(favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations[index])
                        .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedLocationIndex) {
                favouritePressed = true
                isFocused = false
                        }
            .pickerStyle(.palette)

            Spacer()
        }
        
        .navigationTitle("Favorite Locations")
    }
    
    
    func saveLocation(locationIndex: Int) {
        print("Saving...")
        if !newLocation.isEmpty {
            favoritesViewModel.addFavoriteLocation(newLocation, locationIndex: locationIndex)
            newLocation = ""
        }
    }
}

This one just stores favourites:
class FavoritesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Key for UserDefaults
    let favoritesKey = "favoriteLocations"

    // UserDefaults instance
    var defaults: UserDefaults {
        UserDefaults.standard
    }

    // Published property to manage favorite locations
    @Published var favoriteLocations: [String] = []

    // Initialize with default values
    init() {
        self.favoriteLocations = loadFavorites()
    }

    // Load favorite locations from UserDefaults
    func loadFavorites() -> [String] {
        return defaults.stringArray(forKey: favoritesKey) ?? []
    }

    // Save favorite locations to UserDefaults
    func saveFavorites() {
        defaults.set(favoriteLocations, forKey: favoritesKey)
    }

    // Add a new favorite location
    func addFavoriteLocation(_ location: String, locationIndex: Int) {
        // Check if location is already in favorites and limit to 4 locations
        if !favoriteLocations.contains(location) {
            if favoriteLocations.count < 4 {
                favoriteLocations.insert(location, at: locationIndex)
            } else {
                favoriteLocations.remove(at: locationIndex)
                favoriteLocations.insert(location, at: locationIndex)
            }
            saveFavorites() // Save after adding or updating favorites
        }
    }
}

And just the Observed class:
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    
    // THIS IS THE VARIABLE IM TRYING TO SAVE TEXT TO
    @Published var destination: String = ""
    
}


You should still use $app.destination as the text field's binding. Remember, single source of truth.
When the user selects something in the picker, just set app.destination to the selected location.
You only need these states:
@StateObject private var favoritesViewModel = FavoritesViewModel()
@StateObject private var app = AppState()
@State private var selectedLocationIndex: Int?
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

I think it makes more sense for selectedLocationIndex to be optional, to represent the state of not selecting anything.
The rest of the code is straightforward. Note how app.destination is set in .onChange(of: selectedLocationIndex).
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            TextField("Destination", text: $app.destination)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .contentShape(.rect)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 280, height: 60)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                )
            
            Button("Save") {
                saveLocation(locationIndex: selectedLocationIndex ?? 0)
            }
        }
        
        Picker("Favorite Locations", selection: $selectedLocationIndex) {
            ForEach(favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations[index]).tag(Optional.some(index))
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedLocationIndex) { _, newValue in
            if let newValue {
                isFocused = false
                app.destination = favoritesViewModel.favoriteLocations[newValue]
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.palette)

        Spacer()
    }
}


func saveLocation(locationIndex: Int) {
    print("Saving...")
    favoritesViewModel.addFavoriteLocation(app.destination, locationIndex: locationIndex)
    app.destination = ""
}


Thank you so much @Sweeper this works super well now. Thank you so much
